# Routing for custom controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, routes

I'm trying develop a reddit style site which allows users to vote on links. The voting feature goes beyond basic CRUD supported by `resources :links` I've written the up/down actions and linked them to the view but I'm not sure how to handle routing. Could someone demonstrate how I would route to custom controller actions? I've attached my files below. Thanks

I receive this error when I load the view

```
No route matches {:controller=>"links", :action=>"up"}
```

Links Controller https://gist.github.com/1272577

View https://gist.github.com/1272580

Routes https://gist.github.com/1272584

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `resources` mapping with this example:

```
resources :links do
  member do
    match :up
    match :down
  end
end
```

These actions must be available in LinksController class (same as new, create...).
More in [Ruby on Rails Guide: Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Tip: actions changing state of entity should not use GET verb. This is because search bots or accelerator may follow your voting links.
You link should be:

```
<%= link_to "+", up_link_path, :method => :post, :rel => 'nofollow' %>
```

And in controller should modify your entinty only inside `if request.post?`. You should still support GET to not cause 404s.

Comment: I updated the routes file and ran 'rake routes' but this solution didn't work. I also replaced 'post' with 'put' since I'm trying to update attributes, didn't solve it either.

Comment: I changed 'post' to 'put' and also modified my view links `<%= link_to '+', up_link_url(link), :method => :put %> <%= link.points %>` Thanks for the help.